# Testing Omniauth in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, tdd, rspec2, omniauth

We are starting to develop a new website using Rails 3, RSpec 2, and OmniAuth 2. We wanted to follow TDD using RSpec to write the authentication, but we actually don't know where to start. We don't want to test the gem, as it had already been tested, but we want to test the flow of the application and it has routed correctly according to the outcome of the callback.

The best so far is we categorized the problem in two stages:
1- Before the callback: Faking the services like facebook and twitter to return the calls
2- After the callback: getting the results and creating the user and related service

Please guide us and shed us some light :)

Comment: I haven't tried testing OmniAuth yet, but it seem like if you want to test the auth hash that OmniAuth returns (request.env["omniauth.auth"]), the you can use the "OmniAuth.config.mock_auth" method to create a mock auth hash.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Did you checkout the [Wiki](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/wiki/Integration-Testing)?

** Edit **

Perhaps something like (untested):

```
before do
  OmniAuth.config.mock_auth[:twitter] = {
    'uid' => '123545'
  }
end

it "sets a session variable to the OmniAuth auth hash" do
  controller.session[:auth_hash]['uid'].should == '123545'
end
```

Comment: I did, but didn't give me insight on how to stub request.env['omniauth.auth'] for example

Comment: session[:auto_hash] is said to be nil. As this answer is from 2011, maybe OmniAuth has changed

Answer (score 2):

I have experiencing problem for writhing RSpec for OmniauthCallbacksController, do some research on this and it working for me. I am here adding my codes, if anyone found necessary. The tests are for happy path :)

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe OmniauthCallbacksController do
  describe "#linkedin" do
    let(:current_user) { Fabricate(:user) }

    before(:each) do
      OmniAuth.config.test_mode = true
      OmniAuth.config.mock_auth[:linkedin] = OmniAuth::AuthHash.new({provider: :linkedin, uid: '12345', credentials: {token: 'linkedin-token', secret: 'linkedin-secret'}})
      request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]

      @controller.stub!(:env).and_return({"omniauth.auth" => OmniAuth.config.mock_auth[:linkedin]})
      User.stub(:from_auth).and_return(current_user)
    end

    describe "#linkedin" do
      context "with a new linkedin user" do
        before { get :linkedin }
        it "should authenticate user" do
          warden.authenticated?(:user).should == true
        end

        it "should set current_user" do
          subject.current_user.should_not be_nil
        end

        it "should redirect to root_path" do
          response.should redirect_to(root_path)
        end
      end
    end

  end
end
```